# Not able Create GLOBAL TEMPORARY in SYBASE ASE 15.7.0

Tags: t-sql, sap-ase

```
USE XXX
go
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY  TABLE #dbo.tbl_gbl_temp11
(parent_deal_id numeric(10,0) not null,
  deal_id numeric(10,0) not null,
  code_name varchar(100) null
)
go
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.tbl_gbl_temp1') IS NOT NULL
    PRINT '<<< CREATED TABLE dbo.tbl_gbl_temp1 >>>'
ELSE
    PRINT '<<< FAILED CREATING TABLE dbo.tbl_gbl_temp1 >>>'
go
```

---

When I execute the above it gives the following error:

> Number (156) Severity (15) State (2) Server (XXX) Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'TABLE'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE is supported in ASE 16.0 SP02.

Comment: But our DB is Sybase ASE 15.7.0. So we do not have the privilege of "GLOBAL TEMPORARY" :(.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY  TABLE` command in Sybase ASE.

SAP ASE version 16.0 SP2 supports `CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE`

For temp tables use the standard create table syntax, with local temp tables prefixed with a `#` or global temp tables by specifying `tempdb..tbl_name`

So in your case it would be

```
USE XXX
go
CREATE TABLE tempdb..tbl_gbl_temp11   //if the owner is dbo it does not need to be listed.
(parent_deal_id numeric(10,0) not null,
  deal_id numeric(10,0) not null,
  code_name varchar(100) null
)
go

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..tbl_gbl_temp1') IS NOT NULL
    PRINT '<<< CREATED TABLE dbo.tbl_gbl_temp1 >>>'
ELSE
    PRINT '<<< FAILED CREATING TABLE tempdb..tbl_gbl_temp1 >>>'
go
```

[Sybase ASE Transact SQL Reference Guide: Temporary Tables](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc32300.1570/html/sqlug/X10118.htm)

The data will be shared between processes, so you may need to add a spid or other identifier to ensure you don't truncate another processes data when you clean up user/session data.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply it very well helped. But, there is a conceptual doubt, we use tempdb..tbl_gbl_temp1 table to store some information based on a particular request and once the data is accessed from a stored proc we truncate the table since that data in the table is not of use any more. Now, this temp table instance gets created for every user separately (i.e., per connection) or it is the same table accessed by all the users? Basically how will the temp table behave when multiple users use it in parallel.

Comment: The data will be shared between processes, so you may need to add a spid identifier to ensure you don't truncate another processes data.